# MockRestServiceServer does not verify request properly

Tags: spring, testing, integration-testing, spring-integration, spring-test

I'm trying to write an integration test for my spring-integration flow. I wanted to use
MockRestServiceServer to record and match the outgoing requests(using http:outbound-gateway) to the Rest server. However when I call verify method of the mockServer, it's not verifying as it is expected.

I'm writing my tests in the following way:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

mockServer.expect(requestTo("adfasfadf.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET));

// Call spring integration flow here

mockServer.verify();
```

When I check the verify method of MockRestServiceServer, it's not calling match methods of RequestMatchers, which I believe there is something wrong with this logic. Am I missing something here?

```
/**
 * Verify that all expected requests set up via
 * {@link #expect(RequestMatcher)} were indeed performed.
 * @throws AssertionError when some expectations were not met
 */
public void verify() {
    if (this.expectedRequests.isEmpty() || this.expectedRequests.equals(this.actualRequests)) {
        return;
    }
    throw new AssertionError(getVerifyMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After hours of debugging, I've realised that `MockRestServiceServer` runs matchers during execution of the request. So, if you have an exception handler surrounding the request execution, your assertions never going to be asserted properly. 
This code is from `RequestMatcherClientHttpRequest` that runs matchers.

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse executeInternal() throws IOException {
    if (this.requestMatchers.isEmpty()) {
        throw new AssertionError("No request expectations to execute");
    }
    if (this.responseCreator == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("No ResponseCreator was set up. Add it after request expectations, "
                + "e.g. MockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo(\"/foo\")).andRespond(withSuccess())");
    }
    for (RequestMatcher requestMatcher : this.requestMatchers) {
        requestMatcher.match(this);
    }
    setResponse(this.responseCreator.createResponse(this));

    return super.executeInternal();
}
```

I think this should be considered as a bug, since I believe that assertions must be executed after application execution.

Comment: Hi. Is there a ticket related to this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `MockRestServiceServer` before, but looks like this is great feature. Thank you for pointing that out!

Anyway, according to its source code we have:

```
public static MockRestServiceServer createServer(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        Assert.notNull(restTemplate, "'restTemplate' must not be null");
        MockRestServiceServer mockServer = new MockRestServiceServer();
        RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory factory = mockServer.new RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
        return mockServer;
    }
```

Pay attention, please, to the `RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory`.

So, your `RequestMatchers` can be invoked only if you use that modified `RestTemplate`.

Hence you have to inject it to your `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.
Or even better share the `RestTemplate` instance between that gateway and this `MockRestServiceServer`.

Comment: I was using the same rest template between <int-http-outbound-gateway> and MockRestServiceServer. It was because of request matchers is executed during request execution, that leads the integration flow to catch the created assertion error.

Comment: Is there a solution for the issue, or am I just not able to read it from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you don't create a response with the mockserver. I had a similar issue and this was the solution (using `andRespond()` is the crucial part):

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo("adfasfadf.com"))
    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
    .andRespond(withSuccess());
```